# Apple developer account with multiple developers

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter, account

We are 4 developers on the team working for a company.Does each developer have to buy his own apple developer account?.

Edit: I understand that the apple developer organization membership is better for us since we are developing for company. My question is, if we get an apple developer organization membership does each member of the team need to buy his own account to be able to build the application?

Comment: nope, that would never make sense, you can add all the team members to a single developer account and everybody can manage that account, and I guess this question doesn't belong here.

Comment: You will need to pay one only(on behalf of company). and invite 4 apple id to your team

Comment: The account has to be an organization account to be able to add other developers right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one developer account for company, and developers must add to it as developers and app managers and you will not need more account.